# Strange ProcessorAffinity issue with IEXPLORE.exe

Tags: c#, multithreading, internet-explorer

I need to launch IE and set the affinity to a particular single CPU.
When running the following c# code, as expected notepad.exe is started and has it's affinity set to just cpu2, strangely iexplore.exe is started with its affinity set to just cpu0.  No matter what I set ProcessorAffinity to iexplore.exe always goes to cpu0.

I have tested this on 4 core xp 32 bit and 4 core 2008 64 bit, both IE8.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Launch
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        lauchWithAffinity("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
        lauchWithAffinity("c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE");
    }
    static void lauchWithAffinity(string exePath)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = exePath;
        Process myProcess =Process.Start(start);
        myProcess.ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)4; //3rd cpu aka cpu2 
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity.aspx
    }

}
```

Comment: I put a MessageBox.Show(myProcess.ProcessorAffinity.ToString()); after setting the Affinity from 15 to 4, the msgbox prints 4, what are you expecting that doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried to put a `try catch` around the `launchWithAffinity` method to see if an exception gets thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your program and it works fine for me. I even checked in the task manager and the affinity of `iexplore.exe` is set to CPU 2.

Comment: When iexplore.exe is running on CPU 2 can you try launching a second instance on CPU3?  It always seem to appear on the CPU the initial instance was allocated to.

Comment: @user1385705: Hmm you seem to be right. I can start other processes like this and they work correctly, but iexplore seems to keep the same affinity for the next instances. I'm testing on Windows 7 32bit btw.

Comment: @user1385705: Actually, I wrote another test that starts iexplore.exe with both affinities and then reads the affinities of all processes in the system and they display correctly (4 and 8 for the two instances of iexplore). Might be a bug with the task manager?

Comment: I thought the task manager might be wrong but running the sunspider benchmark on 2 separate instances of ie that illegibly had different affinities loaded the same CPU.  Even stranger is that if you start it with different urls it appears to obey the affinity request.   Never mind.  The reason I need to lock IE down to a single CPU is because it runs 20 times slower rendering large pages (2MB +) when you give it multiple CPUs so I shouldn't be surprised that it behaves completely erratically.  MS really need to re-write it from scratch.  Re-theming it every few years isn't fooling anyone.